# use command hexo deploy and there are a error --cannot spawn sh:no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, git, github, hexo

[image]

My computer system is windows10 and I am building a personal blog by hexo.
it generate a error after I use command **hexo deploy**.
error:**cannot spawn sh:no such file or directory**
how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/10/setting-up-hexo-on-windows/ says you have to execute the commands in git-bash (where `sh` is available). You execute from cmd.exe and do not have `sh` in your path, so it is not found and does not work. Execute the command from git-bash and it should probably work fine.